# constexpr constructor gives a different result when evaluated at compile time by GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++14, constexpr

The constructor uses a function taking a reference and returning by value while repeatedly modifying a data member:

```
constexpr int   vv(int   x) {return x;}
constexpr int & rr(int & x) {return x;}
constexpr int   rv(int & x) {return x;}

constexpr struct S {
    int x {0};
    template<typename F> constexpr S(F f) {x = f(x) + 1; x = f(x) + 1;}
} s(rv); // s.x is 1 if function rv is used, 2 otherwise.
static_assert(s.x == 2, "");
```

It is only the function `rv` which gives the unexpected result when used in the constructor. If `vv` or `rr` is passed instead then `s.x` is 2 as expected.

I noticed the behavior on GCC 5.4.1 ARM and it appears to be the same in all versions of GCC that support C++14. Clang gives the expected result of 2 in all cases. Neither GCC nor Clang give any warnings with Wall and Wextra enabled.

Is this example valid C++14 and a bug in GCC? I read the list of restrictions on constant expressions in the standard and see nothing obvious it violates but I'm not sure I understand all the technical details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is certainly intended to be well-formed. I believe GCC performs a revised form of memoization; back in C++11, objects could not be modified in constant expressions, hence it was perfectly fine to cache function results. In fact, it's quite apparent from a few Clang bug reports that GCC did exactly that, see e.g. [here](https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=15552):

> Clang's constexpr implementation does not perform caching. In C++14,
>   it's not even clear whether caching will be possible, so it seems like
>   a waste of time to invest in it now.

They obviously had to introduce some additional analysis in C++14, and they made a mistake: they assumed that any `constexpr` object's subobject cannot be modified during its lifetime. That clearly doesn't hold during the period of construction of the enclosing object. If we use a temporary instead of `x`, [the code compiles](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/GCXr2KryltopL6uw). If we put the whole thing into a `constexpr` function and remove s's `constexpr` specifier, [it works](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/58RZqwXtae9LrC5v).

Funnily enough, `rr`'s and `vv`'s results are also cached, but the same reference being returned works fine, and call by value avoids that problem altogether :)

Reported as [79520](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79520).